# Is the “the Boredom Room” the best translation of Japanese employment jargon, “Oidashibeya” - the special section or unit to pen unwanted employees?

Tags: word-choice

New York Times (August 16) carries an article reporting Sonny’s case of establishing “the boredom Room” to accommodate ‘regular' employees whom they want to get rid of under the title, “Layoffs taboo, **Japan workers are sent to the Boredom Room**.”
http://www.nytimes.com/2013/08/17/business/global/layoffs-illegal-japan-workers-are-sent-to-the-boredom-room.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0

Ahead of this article, the Asahi, a leading Japanese newspaper ran a campaign recently against the prevailing practices of Japanese big companies such as Panasonic, Sonny, Toshiba, Sharp, NEC, Ricoh, Fuji Zerox, IBM Japan and Asahi Life Insurance installing so-called “追い出し部屋 - Oidashibeya (chase-out room by its literal translation)” to streamline workforces under the titles of “Career Challenge Program,” “Career Development (Design) Room,” and “New Business Exploitation Room.”

As the firing and layoffs of regular employees for the employers’ one-sided reasons or convenience is strictly restricted by law, big companies have worked out the idea of setting up “chase-out room,” where they pen employees whom they no longer want to keep and wait them voluntarily leave the company.

‘Oidashibeya’ is not necessarily “boredom room” where occupants are not given job assignment. They are more often given never-achievable, heavy work quota on the contrary, and demanded by the managers to achieve it, or resign the company.

I don’t know whether such cruel labor conditions and irregular working system exist in any of English speaking countries or not. But I’m curious to know what is the right English counterpart to the word, ‘Oidashibeya’– chase (or force)-out room aside “Boredom Room,” which reflects only an aspect of the cruelty of ‘Oidashibeya.’

P.S.

I was surprised to see an inhuman description of reassignment unit which I’d never fancied when I was in office in this article. It says: 
“The United Auto Workers and automakers had created, under union contracts, places where idled **workers were** essentially **warehoused**.”

Comment: I thought those were the employees who were consigned to window seats: 窓際族. Have things changed?

Comment: Robusto-san. I’m glad to have your mention on “madogiwa zoku.” Actually the article refers to“madogiwa zoku- the window-seat-tribe” as unneeded workers who are left with little to do besides gaze out of the window. “Madogiwa zoku” which was current in 1990 through early 2000, were mostly middle managers in middle and older age. They still had their desks and chair at the window side of their office. ‘Oidashibeya’ is far worse and drastically cruel to the derelict employees regardless their age. You can cling to the chair of ‘Madogiwa zoku.’

Comment: Cont. as long as you don’t much care about your face and your pride as a businessman. But you cannot survive in ‘Oidashibeya’ which is something like a disguised sweatshop.

Comment: ‘Boredom room’ sounds more like an 窓際 to me than an 追い出し部屋. I would perhaps translate the latter as something like the ‘Sisyphos room’ or, shunning the awkward use of ‘room’ altogether, say that such employees are “transferred to the Sisyphean department”.

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet. The cruel conditions of ‘Oidashibeya’ where the derelict employees are imposed unachievable assignment and quota can be exactly compared to Sisyphus’ fate. I happened to know Sisyphus’s name only by Albert Camiu’s short essay, ‘The Myth of Sisyphus.’ Most of Japanese (or Asians) may not know who’s Sisyphus. Do you think Sisyphus’ name passes as an unreasonable and cruel treatment without explanation among Anglophones?

Comment: "wait them voluntarily leave" I think it should be: force them to resign or hand in their resignation.

Comment: @YoichiOishi, a Sisyphean task is an idiomatic phrase. Even if people don’t actually know the story of Sisyphos, they are quite likely to know that ‘Sisyphean’ refers to something more or less impossible to overcome.

Comment: @TrevorD. If you could confirm this, I'd be grateful, the closest equivalent to the Japanese "Board room" I could think of (and hence I didn't post) was *constructive dismissal*. Guide at [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/dismissal/unfair-and-constructive-dismissal) This also exists in Italy albeit with slightly modified conditions.

Comment: Mari-Lou A. To me the content ‘Boredom room,’ which doesn’t exactly reflect the meaning of Japanese ‘Oidashineya’ – toss-out room.” is far from ‘constructive’ dismissal. As companies are required to pay extra money (minimum 30%) to a set retirement allowance plus aid and opportunities for the employees’ getting new job when they want to fire regular employees in Japan, they retort to the devise of ‘Oidashineya.’ It’s hard work for Personnel affairs managers.

Comment: Cont. The Asahi Newspaper (Aug. 26) reported the case of ex-Personnel director of Sanyo Co, who resigned Sanyo after ‘successfully’ squeezing out thousands of their employees was offered annual $200,000 plus salary for the Personnel job by the company that needs reduction of work force likewise. But he refused and said “I never would like to return to the same job, even if millions dollars piled on before me.”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The New York City Department of Education has a similar institution, *[reassignment centers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reassignment_centers)*, where teachers accused of misconduct are sent while their cases are resolved. Teachers refer to them as the *[Rubber Room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rubber_Room)*:-

> Allegedly intended to serve as temporary holding facilities for
>   teachers accused of various kinds of misconduct who are awaiting an
>   official hearing, these reassignment centers have become known amongst
>   the "exiled" teachers subculture as "rubber rooms", so named after the
>   padded cells of psychiatric hospitals.

I'd suggest that if you called your *Boredom Room* the *Rubber Room*, most people would understand what you meant.

Comment: +1 (+2 if I could!). Very good find. Something that is both very close in meaning and sounds perfectly idiomatic (even if you haven’t heard of these rubber rooms beforehand, which I hadn’t).

Comment: I'm suprised teachers refer to the  reassignment centers via  *rubber room*, because that term is so closely and commonly associated with psychiatric facilities.

Comment: @jwpat7: I'm not surprised; I suspect it is an inside jape at the administrators.

Comment: On second thought; if the phrase is to be used without explanation, perhaps **Rubber-wall Room** is a tad better

Comment: I'd never heard the term *Rubber Room*. Out of context (or even, in some cases, with *insufficient* context) it could be thought to refer to something else entirely, bearing in mind the slang meaning of *rubber* to refer to a condom.

Comment: TrevorD. I saw the ‘Rubber room’ for teachers’ reshaping being introduced in NYT article dealing with restructuring New York City education system. I can’t remember when, but it was pretty resent.

Comment: "Rubber room" new to me too. Maybe an equivalent in the UK does not exist.

Comment: @YoichiOishi Yes, as Mari-Lou says, it's probably a US phrase - and I'm in the UK!

Comment: @TrevorD and Mari-Lou (I would notify you both, but that is not possible): does this mean that you are also not familiar with ‘rubber room’ as a slang term for a padded cell in UK English? I must admit, I never even considered that this term might be localised to American English. Due, perhaps, to similar terms in other languages (e.g., _Gummizelle_ in German), I have always assumed that the term was somewhat universal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA See comment above as it wasn't sent to you directly.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I've never heard the term, as far as I can recall.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, nope. With context I'd guess its meaning, but isolated, I might think it was a synonym for "soundproof room".

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the Japanese language nor am I an expert on English usage. But the context of the use of the word in Japan suggests to me that it is a waiting room for employees whose jobs are no more "safe".

Borrowing from the spy novel lingo where "safe houses" are frequently used for keeping witnesses out of harm's way under the Witness Protection Programme, maybe we could call this holding area an "unsafe house".

Also, considering that these unwanted employees are on their way out though through coercive prodding, an alternative descriptor could be "exit room".